# VBA Hangs On Pasting a Formula Into a Range

Tags: vba, excel

I've been at this one a while and I have had it working quickly, executing in a couple of seconds over a couple of thousand lines of data, but for some reason it's now constantly locking up at the point of applying the formula to the range.

I've tried it with Index/Match and with Vlookup and both hang at the same point. I then re-worked the whole thing to read all of the data into a couple of arrays, do the lookup entirely in VBA with Application.Worksheetfunction and return the values to a third array before dumping back into Excel, but I abandoned this as the loop was really messy.

Code is as follows, noted at the point it locks - always at the line .Formula = "***Etc. Apologies if it looks a little messy, it's a work in progress with code still to be tidied up.

Any ideas?

```
Sub ppmTracking()

On Error GoTo EndHere

Dim trPath

trPath = "C:\Users\hbartles\Desktop\PPM\Tracking Report\[MichPPMTracking3.xls]MichPPMTracking3"

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Sheets(1).Activate

'''''ORDER STATUS

    With Range("R2", Range("B2").End(xlDown).Offset(0, 16))
        .Formula = "=INDEX('" & trPath & "'!F:F, MATCH($A2&$D2,'" & trPath & "'!A:A,FALSE))" '<<<<LOCKS UP HERE
        .Copy
        .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    End With


'''''LINE STATUS

    With Range("S2", Range("B2").End(xlDown).Offset(0, 17))
        .Formula = "=INDEX('" & trPath & "'!G:G, MATCH($A2&$D2,'" & trPath & "'!A:A,FALSE))" '<<<<LOCKS UP HERE
        .Copy
        .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    End With

''''DESPATCH QUANTITY

    With Range("T2", Range("B2").End(xlDown).Offset(0, 18))
        .Formula = "=INDEX('" & trPath & "'!H:H, MATCH($A2&$D2,'" & trPath & "'!A:A,FALSE))" '<<<<LOCKS UP HERE
        .Copy
        .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        .Replace What:="0", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlWhole
        .Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
    End With

i = 2

    For Each cell In Range("T2", Range("B2").End(xlDown).Offset(0, 18))
        If Not cell.Text = "#N/A" Then
            If Not cell.Text = "" Then
                If cell.Value < Range("F" & i).Value Then cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
            End If
        End If
    i = i + 1
    Next cell



'''''DESPATCH DATE

    With Range("U2", Range("B2").End(xlDown).Offset(0, 19))
        .Formula = "=INDEX('" & trPath & "'!I:I, MATCH($A2&$D2,'" & trPath & "'!A:A,FALSE))" '<<<<LOCKS UP HERE
        .Copy
        .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        .NumberFormat = "General"
    End With

    For Each cell In Range("U2", Range("B2").End(xlDown).Offset(0, 19))
        cell.Value = cell.Value
    Next cell

    With Range("U2", Range("B2").End(xlDown).Offset(0, 19))
        .Replace What:="0", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlWhole
        .NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"
    End With


'''''TRACKING NUMBER

    With Range("V2", Range("B2").End(xlDown).Offset(0, 20))
        .Formula = "=INDEX('" & trPath & "'!J:J, MATCH($A2&$D2,'" & trPath & "'!A:A,FALSE))"
        .Copy
        .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        .Replace What:="0", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlWhole
        .Replace What:="UPS", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart
    End With

'''''FORMAT

    Cells.Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    Rows(1).Font.Color = RGB(256, 256, 256)

    For j = 2 To ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
        If Cells(j, 19).Text = "Cancelled" Then
            ActiveSheet.Range("R" & j).EntireRow.Font.ColorIndex = 3
            ActiveSheet.Range("U" & j, "V" & j).ClearContents
        End If
    Next

    Range("T2").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False



EndHere:



Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic



End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically, been at this for days and as soon as I post it as a question on Stack Exchange I figure out the answer!!

Excel doesn't like doing a lookup to an external file when that file is in XLS format. This code is now snappy when I save the lookup file as an XLSX and change the reference in the variable in VBA.

Now back to the other problem of Access not wanting to export the query data as an XLSX filetype!

Edit: I added a little code to the start of the macro to open the file, save as an xlsx and close it ready for the lookup. Runs smooth as butter now :)

```
Sub ppmTracking()

On Error GoTo EndHere

Dim chgPath
Dim trPath

chgPath = "C:\Users\hbartles\Desktop\PPM\Tracking Report\MichPPMTracking3.xls"
trPath = "C:\Users\hbartles\Desktop\PPM\Tracking Report\[MichPPMTracking3.xlsx]MichPPMTracking3"

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Workbooks.Open Filename:=chgPath
chgPath = Replace(chgPath, "xls", "xlsx")
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=chgPath, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
ActiveWorkbook.Close

Sheets(1).Activate
''And so on....
```